# how to fix vector mapping drivers

Tags: texturing

i have been trying to fix this shader for a while but I don't seem to be getting anywhere and decided to see if anyone could help. the problem is the shader looks fine but as soon as I start rotating the sun lamp the shader doesn't mach up.

[image]

I think It has something to do with the sun rotation drivers I set up in the node editor here is my node setup.

[image]

For some reason the values don't match up with the real world rotation of the sun lamp.

[image]

Here is the blender project if anyone wants to take a crack at it. if you have any suggestions on how to fix it. or you have found the solution please post an answer down below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a gradient from these two vectors you should use a Dot product.
Here I use a constant Z direction that are rotated with your map node. This is then used as one of the inputs for the Dot.

I disconnected the displace because I couldn't understand what you want to do there.

[image]